# Set Mailer's From Address for Each Environment in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, smtp, actionmailer

I am working on a rails app which sends emails from a contact form (via mailer). This all works great.. in development. I have currently set it up to send from the domain `@dev.example.com`) and in production I want the app to send from just `@example.com`. I have added `config.action_mailer.smtp_settings` with all the SMTP information for each environment in the config/environments folder. The issue is when I set the `default from:` address in the mailer, I am hard-coding `@dev.example.com`.

Is there a way to either:

Check which environment the app is currently running in and define an email address/domain for each environment?

or

Get the current environment's `:domain` from the SMTP settings in the respective config/environments/*.rb file?

All other ideas welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
# config/initializers/rails_additional_env.rb:
if defined?(Rails)
  case Rails.env
  when "production"
    RAILS_DOMAIN = "example.com"
  when "development"
    RAILS_DOMAIN = "dev.example.com"
  end
end
```

Then in your mailer

```
default from: "foo@#{RAILS_DOMAIN}"
```

Here is a result for development environment.

[image: screenshot]